# Can "Presilo" Apply to Fruits?

Tags: single-word-requests

The app, "Drops", translates "fruit press" as "fruktopresilo":

https://languagedrops.com/word/en/english/esperanto/translate/fruit_press/

I can't find any other reference where "presilo" is applied to fruits. Nor can I find what would be the correct expression for fruit press.

One option I found was "fruktolikvikilo". Another option might be like with garlic, "ajlopremilo", which would lead to "fruktopremilo". But I am not sure how much veracity to give them.

What do you think?

[unless, of course, that "fruktopresilo" is ultimately the correct term]

Comment: Drops has many errors, from what I’ve seen. It’s good to check the words up and report them if they are incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This translation is incorrect. The verb "presi" does indeed mean "to press", but only as in "printing press". The verb "premi" seems more appropriate to me in this context. ReVo and PIV have the noun "premilo" and those dictionaries even have example sentences about fruits.

A better translation would be "fruktopremilo".

*(I [contacted](https://twitter.com/robin0van0der0v/status/1191131693467480070) the team of Drops to get this error fixed.)*

Answer (score 1):

For fruits, in that context, we use *elpremilo*. Check PIV: [elpremi](http://vortaro.net/#elpremi):

```
Eligi per premado: elpremi sukon el oranĝo (PIV)
```

Note that according to PIV *premilo* also means *aparato por premi fruktojn*, to get juice, oil, ... The meaning relates more the actual pressing of the whole fruit, like an olive press, or the grape press used at the start of the wine making process.

(and yes *presilo* is wrong, unless it's related to [this](https://brandedfruit.com/) :)).

Comment: The correct word is "premilo" according to PIV. Compare the definition and quotes at "premilo" with the definition of "elpremilo".

Comment: @RobinvanderVliet vi pravas. _Premilo_ ja ĝustas. Mi ne scias tamen ĉu tio igas _elpremilo_ malĝusta ... mi vere sentas la mankon de io "eliga" en la kunmetaĵo, ĉar _premilo_ estas tre ampleksa. Mi redaktos la respondon, dankon!